# Flask image upload to S3 only sends HTML

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

I'm trying to create a small app that uploads images to an Amazon S3 bucket. I was finally able to successfully upload *something* however when I checked it in the S3 console all that was uploaded was HTML:

`<input id="image" name="image" type="file">`

Flask:

```
def s3upload(image, acl='public-read'):
    key = app.config['S3_KEY']
    secret = app.config['S3_SECRET']
    bucket = app.config['S3_BUCKET']

    conn = S3Connection(key, secret)
    mybucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket)

    r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool = pool)
    iid = r.incr('image')
    now = time.time()
    r.zadd('image:created_on', now, iid)


    k = Key(mybucket)
    k.key = iid
    k.set_contents_from_string(image)

    return iid

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ImageForm(request.form)
    print 'CHECKING REQUEST'
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print 'VALID REQUEST'
        image = form.image.data
        s3upload(image)
    else:
        image = None

    r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool = pool)
    last_ten = r.zrange('image:created_on', 0, 9)
    print last_ten
    images = []

    key = app.config['S3_KEY']
    secret = app.config['S3_SECRET']
    bucket = app.config['S3_BUCKET']

    conn = S3Connection(key, secret)
    mybucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket)  


    for image in last_ten:

        images.append(mybucket.get_key(image, validate = False))


    return render_template('index.html', form=form, images=images)
```

I was previously told that using `set_contents_from_file` was incorrect and instead to use `set_contents_from_string`

[Flask AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tell'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336955/flask-attributeerror-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-tell/22337402#22337402)

However I feel like this may be the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: There's no error returned, it seems to work however it just uploads that HTML to a text file, no image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only HTML uploads were successful because you are using `set_contents_from_string` method which works only for text based files and **not** images since they are not treated as string. You should use `set_contents_from_file` method as [mentioned in the docs here](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_file).

Retrieve the file object as `request.files['image']` and pass it on to the `set_contents_from_file` method.

```
def s3upload(image, acl='public-read'):
    # do things before
    k.set_contents_from_file(image)
    # do more stuff

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ImageForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        s3upload(request.files['image'])
    # do rest of stuff
```